# Rmarkdown link issue

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to create a personalized link using information from a table pasting the path + the personalized name of the html, which is already saved. But it doesn't understand as a link, I don't if I should use paste or something else. I tried something like that:

```
link <- paste("file:///C:/Users/Documents/TabelaDinamica",
              dfreponsaveis$st_nomeabreviado[1], ".html")

[Clique aqui](link)
```

Comment: Please do not do "tag-fishing" in order to get more views. The [tag:rstudio] tag is somewhat believable, but it is for questions pertaining specifically to the IDE itself, not to the R language. Both [tag:ansible-issue] and [tag:github-issues] are completely random in the context of the question. (I understand that StackExchange often suggests tags, but please be specific about the ones you use and allow.)

Answer (score 0):

````
---
title: Link Demo
---

Two ways to do this. First, using results="asis" on a chunk,

```{r somechunk, results = "asis"}
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/60875005
link <- "https://stackoverflow.com"
cat("[StackOverflow](", link, ")\n")
```

And second, using inline R code in the non-code body of the markdown:

```{r someblock}
link2 <- "https://google.com"
```

[Clique aqui](`r link2`)
````